# Selecting/filtering with JSON Query in Thunder Client

Tags: json, testing, json-query, thunderclient

I am trying to test HTTP responses with Thunder Client in VS Code. The HTTP response I get is:

```json
{
    "currencies": [
        {
            "name": "Btc",
            "count": 17
        },
        {
            "name": "Ltc",
            "count": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

My goal is to test `count` field in each of the item in the array bases on some condition/filter. The test option I want to use is JSON Query. I tried with `json.currencies[name='Btc'].count` query, but the response is:

```
Query: json.currencies[name='Btc'].count > 0 => Actual: undefined
```

How can I check some property with specific conditions inside of the array?

Answer (score 0):

In Thunder Client you can access response array element using index.

so use `json.currencies[0].count`

Comment: I know this feature, but I can not use it because order is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

With the [version 1.18.3](https://github.com/rangav/thunder-client-support/releases/tag/v1.18.3) filtering by property content was introduced.

Answer (score 0):

No need of quotes around Btc

`json.currencies[name=Btc].count`

Comment: note, this is not working if a value has a dot character (potentially some other chars) e.g. json.domain[name=google.com].ip

Comment: Please report on our thunder client GitHub page, will fix it asap.

Comment: done: https://github.com/rangav/thunder-client-support/issues/798